# hwloc/linux warning and PETSc Segmentation Violation error

Tags: parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmpi, petsc

I am trying to run a program using mpirun command (as shown below).

```
mpirun -np 4 python test.py
```

But I am getting following warning first:

```
hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
(warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).
hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
(warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).
hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
(warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).
hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
(warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).
```

Program also depends on PETSc, after the above warning, it shows following error:

```
[1]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[1]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[1]PETSC ERROR: or see https://petsc.org/release/faq/#valgrind
[1]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[1]PETSC ERROR: likely location of problem given in stack below
[1]PETSC ERROR: ---------------------  Stack Frames ------------------------------------
[1]PETSC ERROR: Note: The EXACT line numbers in the stack are not available,
[1]PETSC ERROR:       INSTEAD the line number of the start of the function
[1]PETSC ERROR:       is given.
[1]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[1]PETSC ERROR: Signal received
[1]PETSC ERROR: See https://petsc.org/release/faq/ for trouble shooting.
[1]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.15.5, Sep 29, 2021 
[1]PETSC ERROR: Unknown Name on a real-debug named skynet by pavan Sat Jun 18 10:30:04 2022
[1]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --PETSC_ARCH=real-debug --with-scalar-type=real --with-debugging=1 --with-mpi-dir=/home/pavan/packages/openmpi-4.0.7/opt-gfortran --download-metis=yes --download-parmetis=yes --download-superlu_dist=yes --with-shared-libraries=yes --with-fortran-bindings=1 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11
[1]PETSC ERROR: #1 User provided function() at unknown file:0
[1]PETSC ERROR: Checking the memory for corruption.
[2]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[2]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[2]PETSC ERROR: or see https://petsc.org/release/faq/#valgrind
[2]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[2]PETSC ERROR: likely location of problem given in stack below
[2]PETSC ERROR: ---------------------  Stack Frames ------------------------------------
[2]PETSC ERROR: Note: The EXACT line numbers in the stack are not available,
[2]PETSC ERROR:       INSTEAD the line number of the start of the function
[2]PETSC ERROR:       is given.
[2]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[2]PETSC ERROR: Signal received
[2]PETSC ERROR: See https://petsc.org/release/faq/ for trouble shooting.
[2]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.15.5, Sep 29, 2021 
[2]PETSC ERROR: Unknown Name on a real-debug named skynet by pavan Sat Jun 18 10:30:04 2022
[2]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --PETSC_ARCH=real-debug --with-scalar-type=real --with-debugging=1 --with-mpi-dir=/home/pavan/packages/openmpi-4.0.7/opt-gfortran --download-metis=yes --download-parmetis=yes --download-superlu_dist=yes --with-shared-libraries=yes --with-fortran-bindings=1 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11
[2]PETSC ERROR: #1 User provided function() at unknown file:0
[2]PETSC ERROR: Checking the memory for corruption.
[3]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[3]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[3]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[3]PETSC ERROR: or see https://petsc.org/release/faq/#valgrind
[3]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[3]PETSC ERROR: likely location of problem given in stack below
[3]PETSC ERROR: ---------------------  Stack Frames ------------------------------------
[3]PETSC ERROR: Note: The EXACT line numbers in the stack are not available,
[3]PETSC ERROR:       INSTEAD the line number of the start of the function
[3]PETSC ERROR:       is given.
[3]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[3]PETSC ERROR: Signal received
[3]PETSC ERROR: See https://petsc.org/release/faq/ for trouble shooting.
[3]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.15.5, Sep 29, 2021 
[3]PETSC ERROR: Unknown Name on a real-debug named skynet by pavan Sat Jun 18 10:30:04 2022
[3]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --PETSC_ARCH=real-debug --with-scalar-type=real --with-debugging=1 --with-mpi-dir=/home/pavan/packages/openmpi-4.0.7/opt-gfortran --download-metis=yes --download-parmetis=yes --download-superlu_dist=yes --with-shared-libraries=yes --with-fortran-bindings=1 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11
[3]PETSC ERROR: #1 User provided function() at unknown file:0
[3]PETSC ERROR: Checking the memory for corruption.
[0]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[0]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[0]PETSC ERROR: or see https://petsc.org/release/faq/#valgrind
[0]PETSC ERROR: or try http://valgrind.org on GNU/linux and Apple Mac OS X to find memory corruption errors
[0]PETSC ERROR: likely location of problem given in stack below
[0]PETSC ERROR: ---------------------  Stack Frames ------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Note: The EXACT line numbers in the stack are not available,
[0]PETSC ERROR:       INSTEAD the line number of the start of the function
[0]PETSC ERROR:       is given.
[0]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Signal received
[0]PETSC ERROR: See https://petsc.org/release/faq/ for trouble shooting.
[0]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.15.5, Sep 29, 2021 
[0]PETSC ERROR: Unknown Name on a real-debug named skynet by pavan Sat Jun 18 10:30:04 2022
[0]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --PETSC_ARCH=real-debug --with-scalar-type=real --with-debugging=1 --with-mpi-dir=/home/pavan/packages/openmpi-4.0.7/opt-gfortran --download-metis=yes --download-parmetis=yes --download-superlu_dist=yes --with-shared-libraries=yes --with-fortran-bindings=1 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11
[0]PETSC ERROR: #1 User provided function() at unknown file:0
[0]PETSC ERROR: Checking the memory for corruption.
```

I am new to mpi, so I don't really know what is going here. Any help will be much appreciated. Following are the additional details which might be useful:

- System: Ubuntu 22.04
- OpenMPI - 4.0.7
- PETSc - 3.15.5. Configured PETSc as follows:

```
./configure --PETSC_ARCH=$PETSC_ARCH --with-scalar-type=real --with-debugging=1 --with-mpi-dir=$MPI_INSTALL_DIR \
   --download-metis=yes --download-parmetis=yes --download-superlu_dist=yes \
   --with-shared-libraries=yes --with-fortran-bindings=1 --with-cxx-dialect=C++11
```

- Python - 3.9.12
- gfortran - 9.4.0
- gcc - 9.4.0

Comment: Are you sure your `mpirun` is the one that comes with your OpenMPI? Otherwise, ask the petsc mailing list.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thanks for your comment! I think it is coming from the openmpi installation, I checked using "which mpirun" and location was from the installation. I will try the mailing list.

Also, is there any version dependency between openmpi and petsc to work together?